# llegalArgumentException: Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest-geoMarkerScreen can't be found in the navigation graph

Tags: navigation, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-navigation-bar

I am using jetpack compose navigation in my app but I get IllegalArgumentException while trying to navigate to geoMarkerScreen from homeScreen. The problem seems at the BottomNavigationBar...How can I resolve this? I laready set up the NavHost

```
package com.example.bettehomes.navigation


    import androidx.compose.material3.NavigationBar
    import androidx.compose.material3.NavigationBarItem
    import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
    import androidx.compose.material3.Text
    import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
    import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
    import androidx.navigation.NavController
    import androidx.navigation.compose.currentBackStackEntryAsState
    
    
    @Composable
    fun BottomNavigationBar(navController: NavController) {
        NavigationBar {
            val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
            val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route
    
            BottomNavItem.values().forEach { item ->
                NavigationBarItem(selected = currentRoute == item.route,
                    onClick = {
                        navController.navigate(item.route) {
                            popUpTo(navController.graph.startDestinationId) {
                                saveState = true
                            }
                            launchSingleTop = true
                            restoreState = true
                        }
                    }, icon = { Icon(item.icon, contentDescription = null) },label = { Text(item.label) })
                        }
        }

}
```

The error appears to be at:

```
com.example.bettehomes.navigation.BottomNavigationBarKt$BottomNavigationBar$1$1$1.invoke(BottomNavigationBar.kt:23)
                                                                                                        at com.example.bettehomes.navigation.BottomNavigationBarKt$BottomNavigationBar$1$1$1.invoke(BottomNavigationBar.kt:21)
```

NavHost.kt:

```
package com.example.bettehomes.navigation

import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.SnackbarHostState
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.collectAsState
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.hilt.navigation.compose.hiltViewModel
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import com.example.bettehomes.data.login.AuthViewModel
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.GeoMarkerViewModel
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.authscreens.HomeScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.authscreens.LoginScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.authscreens.PrivacyPolicyScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.authscreens.SignUpScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.authscreens.TermsAndConditionsScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.authscreens.settings.SettingsScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.authscreens.splash.SplashScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.mapscreens.GeoMarkerScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.mapscreens.MapsScreen

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun AppNavigation(
    snackbarHostState: SnackbarHostState,
    geoMarkerViewModel: GeoMarkerViewModel,
    fetchLocationUpdates: () -> Unit,
    authViewModel: AuthViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val isAuthenticated by authViewModel.isAuthenticated.collectAsState()
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            BottomNavigationBar(navController = navController)
        }
    ) {it
        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screens.SplashScreen) {
            composable(Screens.SplashScreen) {
                SplashScreen(openAndPopUp = { route, popUp ->
                    navController.navigateAndPopUp(route, popUp)
                })
            }
            composable(Screens.HomeScreen) {
                HomeScreen()
            }

            composable(Screens.MapScreen) {
                MapsScreen(
                    snackbarHostState = snackbarHostState,
                    navController = navController,
                    fetchLocationUpdates = fetchLocationUpdates
                )
            }

            composable(Screens.SignUpScreen) {
                SignUpScreen(navController)
            }
            composable(Screens.LoginScreen) {
                LoginScreen(navController)
            }
            composable(Screens.TermsAndConditions) {
                TermsAndConditionsScreen(navController)
            }
            composable(Screens.PrivacyPolicy) {
                PrivacyPolicyScreen(navController)
            }

            if (isAuthenticated) {
                composable(Screens.GeoMarkerScreen) {
                    GeoMarkerScreen(geoMarkerViewModel, navController)
                }
            } else {
                composable(Screens.LoginScreen) {
                    LoginScreen(navController)
                }
            }

            composable(Screens.SettingsScreen) {
                SettingsScreen(
                    restartApp = { route ->
                        navController.clearAndNavigate(
                            route,
                            startDestination = 1
                        )
                    },
                    openScreen = { route -> navController.navigate(route) }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BottomNavItem.kt:

```
package com.example.bettehomes.navigation

import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Add
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Home
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Search
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Settings
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.ImageVector

enum class BottomNavItem(val route: String, val icon: ImageVector, val label: String) {
    Home("homeScreen", Icons.Default.Home, "Home"),
    Create("geoMarkerScreen", Icons.Default.Add, "Create"),
    Search("mapsScreen", Icons.Default.Search, "Search"),
    Settings("settingsScreen", Icons.Default.Settings, "Settings");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only navigate to a destination that you defined in your `NavHost` with the `composable` builder function. You define a `Screens.GeoMarkerScreen` route, so if you want to navigate to that screen, `item.route` in `navController.navigate(item.route)` must be exactly equal to whatever `Screens.GeoMarkerScreen` contains.

Since your question does not tell us what an `item` is or what its `route` property contains, I can only deduce from the exception that is thrown that it does *not* contain a valid navigation route. You can easly verify that by setting a breakpoint at that line and compare the actual content of `item.route` with `Screens.GeoMarkerScreen`.

Comment: I have added BottomNavItem, and I think it consists of routes but I am using Screens.GeoMarkerScreen as route input? Are these not exactly the same?

Comment: `BottomNavItem.Create.route` contains the string `"geoMarkerScreen"`. This is not correct, it must be set to `Screens.GeoMarkerScreen` instead (the same applies to the other routes where the string literal must be replaced by the appropriate `Screens` type).

Answer (score 0):

What worked was:

```
package com.example.bettehomes.navigation

import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.SnackbarHostState
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.GeoMarkerViewModel
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.authscreens.HomeScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.authscreens.LoginScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.authscreens.PrivacyPolicyScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.authscreens.SignUpScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.authscreens.TermsAndConditionsScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.authscreens.settings.SettingsScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.authscreens.splash.SplashScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.mapscreens.GeoMarkerScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.mapscreens.MapsScreen

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun AppNavigation(
    snackbarHostState: SnackbarHostState,
    geoMarkerViewModel: GeoMarkerViewModel,
    fetchLocationUpdates: () -> Unit,
    ) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    var isAuthenticated by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            BottomNavigationBar(navController = navController)
        }
    ) {it
        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screens.SplashScreen) {
            composable(Screens.SplashScreen) {
                SplashScreen(openAndPopUp = { route, popUp ->
                    navController.navigateAndPopUp(route, popUp)
                })
            }
            composable(Screens.HomeScreen) {
                HomeScreen()
            }

            composable(Screens.MapScreen) {
                MapsScreen(
                    snackbarHostState = snackbarHostState,
                    navController = navController,
                    fetchLocationUpdates = fetchLocationUpdates
                )
            }

            composable(Screens.SignUpScreen) {
                SignUpScreen(navController)
            }
            composable(Screens.LoginScreen) {
                LoginScreen(navController)
            }
            composable(Screens.TermsAndConditions) {
                TermsAndConditionsScreen(navController)
            }
            composable(Screens.PrivacyPolicy) {
                PrivacyPolicyScreen(navController)
            }

            composable(Screens.GeoMarkerScreen) {
                GeoMarkerScreen(geoMarkerViewModel, navController) {
                    isAuthenticated = true }
            }

            composable(Screens.SettingsScreen) {
                SettingsScreen(
                    restartApp = { route ->
                        navController.clearAndNavigate(
                            route,
                            startDestination = 1
                        )
                    },
                    openScreen = { route -> navController.navigate(route) }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```